# Strange behaviour in framework 4.0 related to gridview - remove update/cancel button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a asp.net gridview added with `CommandField` as below:

```
<asp:Commandfield buttontype="link" showeditbutton="true" headertext="edit" visible="true" />
```

This will display edit as first column in the grid.

If  i click any of the edit row then i will not get any update cancel row. Consecutively if i click any other button after edit i get update/Cancel row.

I have not added any update cancel template.

I do not want this to happen.I do not want the update/cancel row as i have my own code in `Row_Edit` event

Observation: this happens in framework 4.0 only